# How to change the width of cursor in React native TextInput?

Tags: react-native

I want to make the blinking cursor thin in TextInput, how to do that? The normal width is like 3px, I want it to have 1px.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For android you can follow this steps:

step 1: Create editext_cursor.xml and place it under res->drawable directory.

`android/app/src/main/res/drawable/editext_cursor.xml`

step 2: inside editext_cursor.xml paste this:

```js
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <size android:width="1dip" />
        <solid android:color="#010101" />
    </shape>
```

and here you can change the width to whatever you want.

step 3: add that line to `android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml`

```js
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>

        <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@drawable/editext_cursor</item> <-- add this

    </style>

</resources>
```

step 4: rebuild your app